# Read data from database located at server in android

Tags: android, database

I have one database file whose name is menu.db and this file is located at server now i want to read data from this database.
i also have registration page on the application i am working on, as user press submit button then all the user information should be store on that database at server.
if anyone solved this problem then please help me.

if any one knows then please help me.

Comment: Which database are you dealing with? Is it SQLite?

Comment: Do you want to access database which is located on remote server? Then I think the best way is to have some web services built on top of the database and make http connection from your android application to the web server.

Comment: @Karthik Palanivelu : thanks for reply i want exactly same as you described can you have any sample or any link so that i can work on that direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the following code. It authenticates the user password. you should call this method inside doBackground() of AsyncTask extended Class.

```
public boolean authenticate(String strUsername, String strPassword)
{
    boolean bReturn = false;

    InputStream pInputStream = null;
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> pNameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    pNameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", strUsername));
    pNameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", strPassword));

    try
    {
        HttpClient pHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        String strURL = p_strServerIP + "Login.php";
        HttpPost pHttpPost = new HttpPost(strURL);
        pHttpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pNameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse pHttpResponse = pHttpClient.execute(pHttpPost);
        HttpEntity pHttpEntity = pHttpResponse.getEntity();
        pInputStream = pHttpEntity.getContent();

        BufferedReader pBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pInputStream,"iso-8859-1"),8);

        StringBuilder pStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String strLine = pBufferedReader.readLine();
        pInputStream.close();
        if(strLine != null)
        {
            if((strLine).equals("permit"))
            {
                bReturn = true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Caught Exception @ authenticate(String strUsername, String strPassword):" + e.toString());
    }

    return bReturn;
}
```

The class you extend from AsyncTask should be something like

```
class ConnectionTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> 
{
    private SharedPreferences mSettings;
    private Context mContext;
    ConnectionTask(SharedPreferences settings, Context context)
    {
        mSettings = settings;
        mContext = context;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) 
    {
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Authentication over.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) 
    {
        pVerifier.authenticate(params[0], params[1]);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for peace of code i have completed the authentication part only challenging part is that open database at server read record from there and if possible enter new record also.

Comment: What language you using for web services?

Comment: i am using java as a language SqLite as a database.

Comment: I would prefer MySQL and PHP or PostgreSQL and PHP. It would make life easier.